# How to show the contents of a lan server through another internet-connected

Tags: internet, intranet

I need some help. We have 2 servers (centos and ubuntu). 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2.

On 10.0.0.1 We have our intranet services (web applications) (10.0.0.1/sis1, 10.0.0.1/sis2...)

On 10.0.0.2 We have our website published on the internet with a domain example.com

Now we need to give access for the public through our website to intranet applications. We want to create a link like www.example.com/intranet/ upon entering the link, we want to show the web applications that are on the server 10.0.0.1 but this server does not have a domain for internet. What we can do? Please help us. Thank you!

Comment: What software are you running?  Pretty general question.  Since 10.0.0.2 seems to be public accessible, you just need a proxy setup.  Something like mod_proxy to forward to 10.0.0.1.

Comment: Apache2 both. PHP5.3 on intranet and 5.5 for the public server. we have another server for database.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Apache, you can use reverse proxy through mod_proxy to redirect requests from 10.10.0.2 /intranet to the web server at 10.0.0.1.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html